# updating website without deleting database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I am using docker for my django project with ubuntu server.
When I was chaning something always I am removing my docker images and building it again and my database also removed and I have to be populate my database again.

I am trying these steps:
pulling new code from git

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker-compose up --build -d
```

and as I mentioned my database also removed.

I have tried without stopping and removing.
Only `docker-compose up --build -d`
but it did not worked.
Also I tried
`docker-compose restart`
it also not worked.

What I have to be tried. Please note that I am new in docker and django. Its my first project.

**docker-compose.yml** file

```
    version: '3'

services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  postgres:
    container_name:  postgres-db
    image:           postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - 5432:5432 # Bind host port 5432 to PostgreSQL port 5432
    volumes:
      - ./pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8


  web:
    container_name: name
    build: .
    restart: "always"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,localhost
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
      - TIMEOUT=100
      - HTTP_PORT=8000
      - STATS_PORT=8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./media:/code/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7

# Ensure that Python outputs everything that's printed inside
# the application rather than buffering it.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APP_ROOT /name

# Copy in your requirements file
ADD req.txt /req.txt

# Install build deps, then run `pip install`, then remove unneeded build deps all in a single step. Correct the path to your production requirements file, if needed.
RUN pip install virtualenvwrapper
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -U pip
RUN /venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /req.txt

# Copy your application code to the container (make sure you create a .dockerignore file if any large files or directories should be excluded)
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}/static
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
COPY mime.types /etc/mime.types

# uWSGI will listen on this port
EXPOSE 8000

# Call collectstatic (customize the following line with the minimal environment variables needed for manage.py to run):
#RUN if [ -f manage.py ]; then /venv/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; fi

# Start uWSGI
CMD [ "/venv/bin/uwsgi", "--ini", "/fec/uwsgi.ini"]
```

Comment: You can use a separate docker image for your database, and thus let your "Django docker" connect to the "database docker".

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand it clearly, could you please clarify it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose has its own commands for dealing with the used images in the `docker-compose.yaml`. There is no need to use `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`.

Try

`docker-compose --help`

I suspect that only your `web` service is changing. So this should suffice to only rebuild and start the `web` service:

```
docker-compose stop web
docker-compose rm web
docker-compose up --no-deps --build -d
```

Comment: I tried with your guide. firstly i get this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path/pgdb'
[20149] Failed to execute script docker-compose` . pgdb is created with root user i changed its owner and permission then retry `docker-compose up --no-deps --build -d` but get this error `OSError: Can not read file in context: /path/pgdb/pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat
[20170] Failed to execute script docker-compose`

Comment: Where are you executing these commands? They must be executed on the `host` in the directory where your docker-compose.yml is. What is your OS?

Comment: yes I executing them in the directory which docker-compose.yml is located. OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Mmh. I am on a similar System and I have never encountered this error. Sorry. My remote debugging skills are limited at this point. I suspect a Version mismatch docker vs. docker-compose. Make Sure they are installed from The Docker repos and not the official Ubuntu repos.